# How to send Retrofit POST body as JSON String?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, converters, webapi

I have a service like below. I call the method `Retroifit` library. The service works when I send the paramter with `@Body Test` type but I want work with `@Body String` that i don't create a `Test` class and using this in `@Body`. I create a `JSONObject` and convert this to `String` but in this way, the program doesn't work! Can you help me or suggest a solution for this?

My Web API:

```
    [Route("TestService"), HttpPost, IgnoreDataLog]
    public async Task<Result<TestResult>> Add(Test pmDeviceObj)
    {
        var listResult = await pmService.AddAsync(pmDeviceObj);
        return listResult;
    }
```

Android part:

```
@POST("TestService")
Call<Result<TestResult>> TestService(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,@Body String body);
```

Call Service in Android-> I get the StatusCode 400 with the below code

```
    JSONObject jsonBody=new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonBody.put("Id",73);
        jsonBody.put("seri","55656573");
        jsonBody.put("code","fc24009b9160");
        jsonBody.put("sID",8);
    }catch (JSONException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    retrofit2.Call<Result<TestResult>> call1=service.TestService("application/json",jsonBody.toString());
```

If I use the below code in the Android part, everything works correct and I take the data.

```
@POST("TestService")
Call<Result<TestResult>> TestService(@Header("Content-Type") String content_type,@Body Test inputValue);

 Test test=new Test(73,"556565","fc24009b9160",8);
 retrofit2.Call<Result<TestResult>> call1=service.TestService("application/json",test);
```

Comment: check the link https://medium.com/@robertas.konarskis/how-to-send-a-string-body-with-retrofit-70319c25bf33

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `Retrofit` considers `String` as a 'normal' object that has to be converted to a JSON and is not aware that it already is a JSON represntation of object.

If you have `HttpLogginInterceptor` configured, you should see that (simplified example) your JSON string:

> {"sId": "8"}

actually goes like:

> "{\"sId\": \"8\"}"

To prevent this happen you need to use something like the comment suggests `ScalarsConverterFactory`. First you need to set dependencies for it:

**For Gradle**

```
dependencies {    
    implementation “com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0”
}
```

**or for Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
    <artifactId>converter-scalars</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After done that you need to add the converter factory to your Retrofit, like (added also logging to be easily tested):

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(MY_URL)
        // be sure to add this before gsonconverterfactory!
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())                
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory
                .create())
        .client(client).build();
myApi = retrofit.create(MY_API_CLASS);
```